# H ow to solve this limit ? $\lim_{x\to \pi/4}{(\tan x)^{\tan 2x}} $

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{x\to \pi/4}{(\tan x)^{\tan 2x}} $$

I think this is the second remarkable limit, but here is how to solve it - I do not know. help me please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim _{ x\to \pi /4 }{ (\tan  x)^{ \tan  2x } } \\ x-\frac { \pi  }{ 4 } =t\\ \lim _{ t\rightarrow 0 }{ { \left( \tan { \left( t+\frac { \pi  }{ 4 }  \right)  }  \right)  }^{ \tan { 2\left( t+\frac { \pi  }{ 4 }  \right)  }  } } =...\\ \\ \tan { \left( t+\frac { \pi  }{ 4 }  \right)  } =\frac { \tan { t } +1 }{ 1-\tan { t }  } =1+\frac { 2\tan { t }  }{ 1-\tan { t }  } \\ \tan { \left( 2t+\frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  \right)  } =-\cot { 2t } \\ \lim _{ t\rightarrow 0 }{ { \left( \tan { \left( t+\frac { \pi  }{ 4 }  \right)  }  \right)  }^{ \tan { 2\left( t+\frac { \pi  }{ 4 }  \right)  }  } } =\lim _{ t\rightarrow 0 }{ { \left( 1+\frac { 2\tan { t }  }{ 1-\tan { t }  }  \right)  }^{ -\cot { 2t }  } } =\\ =\lim _{ t\rightarrow 0 }{ { \left[ { { \left( 1+\frac { 2\tan { t }  }{ 1-\tan { t }  }  \right)  } }^{ \frac { 1-\tan { t }  }{ 2\tan { t }  }  } \right]  }^{ \frac { 2\tan { t }  }{ 1-\tan { t }  } \quad \cdot \left( -\cot { 2t }  \right)  } } ={ e }^{ \lim _{ t\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { 2\tan { t }  }{ 1-\tan { t }  } \quad \cdot \left( -\cot { 2t }  \right)  }  }=...\\ \lim _{ t\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { 2\tan { t }  }{ 1-\tan { t }  } \quad \cdot \left( -\cot { 2t }  \right)  } =-\lim _{ t\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { 2\sin { t }  }{ \cos { t-\sin { t }  }  } \quad \cdot \frac { \left( \cos { t } -\sin { t }  \right) \left( \cos { t } +\sin { t }  \right)  }{ 2\sin { t\cos { t }  }  }  } =-1\\ { e }^{ \lim _{ t\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { 2\tan { t }  }{ 1-\tan { t }  } \quad \cdot \left( -\cot { 2t }  \right)  }  }={ \quad e }^{ -1 }\\ $$

> $$\lim _{ x\to \pi /4 }{ (\tan  x)^{ \tan  2x } } ={ e }^{ -1 }$$

Answer (score 1):

Take Log we have: $\tan(2x)\ln(\tan x)= \dfrac{2\tan x\ln(\tan x)}{1-\tan^2 x}$. Put $u = \tan x$, then the limit $l = 2\displaystyle \lim_{u \to 1}\dfrac{\ln u}{1-u^2}=-1$, by L'hospitale rule. Thus the original limit $L = e^l = e^{-1} = \dfrac{1}{e}$

Comment: The OP tagged the question "limits-without-lhopital"

Comment: Of course, tags are not considered part of the question, just a way to find the question and sort them. The OP should have mentioned it in the question proper.

Comment: Alternatively, note $\ln u \sim u-1$ and $2\displaystyle \lim_{u \to 1}\dfrac{ u-1}{1-u^2}=2\displaystyle \lim_{u \to 1}\dfrac{-1}{1+u} = -1$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  It is part of the question since a question cannot be posted without tags.  And anyway, I believe that answerers need to spend enough time considering a question, and it's tag(s), if the goal is to answer the question at hand.  To answer too quickly, or to make assumptions about what an OP means (!) is not useful, nor is it desirable.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not what tags are for. Tags are not meant to clarify the question - the question should be clear, and this answerer answered the question. The only time I read the tags for a question is when the question is unclear and I'm struggling for a context. From the StackOverflow meta: "Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories.

Tags can also be used to help you identify questions that are interesting or relevant to you."

Comment: All of that is about people being able to find questions, not about clarifying a question.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews OP tagged "limits-without-lhopital". Therefore, OP wants an answer without L'hopital. Don't know why you're making such a fuss about it.

Comment: First of all, I don't think I'm making a "fuss." I'm pointing out a cultural thing. The purpose of tags on this site is not for clarification. The OP asked a question, and it honestly seems about equally likely that OP mis-tagged it as that OP forgot to include the information in the question. Usually, the OP is way more clear about the question than the tags, so I trust the question.

Comment: Well, you and I differ on the matter, @Thomas. My initial comment was left simply to inform the answerer here; I said nothing to the effect that it was "wrong". That's all.  I did not downvote the answer, or otherwise defame the answerer. You are the one who decided to to take exception to my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Set $x=\pi/4-t$ so the base becomes
$$
\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-t\right)=\frac{1-\tan t}{1+\tan t}
$$
and the exponent is
$$
\tan2x=\cot2t=\frac{1-\tan^2t}{2\tan t}
$$
so we really have to compute
$$
\lim_{t\to0}\left(\frac{1-\tan t}{1+\tan t}\right)^{1/\tan t}
$$
and then take its square root.

Let's split it into the limit from the right and from the left. For $t\to0^+$, let's set $\tan t=1/u$, so the limit becomes
$$
\lim_{u\to\infty}\left(\frac{u-1}{u+1}\right)^u=
\lim_{u\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{2}{u+1}\right)^u=
\lim_{u\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{2}{u+1}\right)^{u+1}
\left(1-\frac{2}{u+1}\right)^{-1}
$$
Can you finish and also do the limit from the left?